# How to pull text output from network devices (show commands) and pass the data to SNMP?

Tags: ubiquiti, gpon

I work at a small ISP and we have a 3rd party monitoring tool called Logicmonitor that pulls SNMP data from our networking equipment. We currently utilize Calix and Ubiquiti equipment, but neither show to have SNMP data readily available for CPU temps, Fan speeds, Voltages, etc. I attempted to find them with an SNMPwalk or MIB browser, but came up with nothing.

Is there a way to use ansible to use a playbook to run the show commands, parse the data, and then pass the values somehow to SNMP or associate them to OID's so that Logicmonitor can use that data?

I'm truly at a loss on how to pull this data and get it into our dashboards unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, if the MIB does not support it, then you cannot use SNMP for it. You really need to check with the manufacturer about the lack of SNMP support for values you want.

Comment: Ubiquiti's product portfolio is very diverse, but at least their EdgeSwitch equipment seems to provide the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use ansible to use a playbook to run the show commands, parse the data, and then pass the values somehow to SNMP or associate them to OID's so that Logicmonitor can use that data?

You can use Ansible to query and extract the desired data via console interface. However, there's no way to (re)insert that data into the MIB database (unless you wedge it into a customizable text field like *contact* or *location*). You'd need to find a way to make your software import the data using a script.